# On non-existent merge() method mentioned in an OCPJP 8 exam topic in Stream - IZ0-809 exam

Tags: java, java-8, scjp, ocpjp

The last exam objective under "Java Streams" section in [1Z0-809 exam](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-809&p_org_id=1001&lang=US) (Java 8 exam) reads:

> Use of `merge()` and `flatMap()` methods of the Streams

There is no `merge()` method in `Stream` interface!

There is a `merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)` method in `Map` but the exam objective clearly says "`merge()` and `flatMap()` methods of the Streams". Of course there is a `flatMap()` method in `Stream` interface. So what am I missing? Is the exam objective wrong? If its a mistake in the exam objective, how to contact Oracle for reporting this problem?

Comment: Do these exams expect you to do guessing from title or is there associated material to read?

Comment: This is clearly an error in the exam objective. I'll get this fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please let me know by when the exam objective will be fixed in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw that it got fixed in the exam objectives - http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-809

Thank you Stuart Marks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a mistake in exam objectives. Even in prerelease Stream API versions there were no `merge()` method. Also according to the public sources, there are no plans or even proposals to add such method in future Java versions. Probably `map()` method was meant or something else.